# htaccess url masking mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, masking

I have done some URL masking and it all works very nicely. I have one issue that I am trying to resolve now:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/clubs/(.*)/$ teams.php?competition=$1&season=$2&teamid=$3
```

with the above I can access the same page 2 ways, `www.domain.com/premier-league/2010-2011/arsenal/` and `www.domain.com?competition=premier-league&season=2010-2011&teamid=arsenal`

is there a way in my rewrite rule I can redirect the URL (301 ideally) is someone does it through the untidy way "`www.domain.com?competition=premier-league&season=2010-2011&teamid=arsenal`"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you add another rewrite rule after this one that matches your 'inverse' pattern, and mark both as the [L]ast rule, that might work. I first rewrite the url to include the query string, and [C]hain that one to the next rule. After that we [R]edirect the browser.

```
RewriteRule ^(.)/(.)/clubs/(.*)/$ teams.php?competition=$1&season=$2&teamid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1%{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule ^teams.php?competition=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&season=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&teamid=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1/$2/clubs/$3/ [R=301,L]
```

Note I haven't tested this or the regex of the second rule. Might need to adjust the character ranges a bit. Also I haven't tested the query string rewrite in the second rule.

Edit: See here for some common use cases of `mod_rewrite`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Sorry, but `RewriteRule` does not work with query string this way.

Comment: is there a way I can redirect all pages from my old site to my new domains home page?

Comment: Ah, obviously! You need to append it using a rewrite chain. Let me check if that works...

Comment: @Richard G, check the link I just posted: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html